# To display two graphs from two different columns from csv file using matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot

I am using following code to plot 2 different plot(count of visit) from 2 different columns of a CSV file. But the 2nd graph is displaying only after I close the 1st graph. Is it possible to display 2 plots together?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

output2 =pandas.read_csv('Place.csv')
place_plot= output2.Place.value_counts().plot(kind="bar",x=output2["Place"],title="Count",legend=False)
plt.show()
capital_plot= output2.Capital.value_counts().plot(kind="bar",x=output2["Capital"],title="Count",legend=False)
plt.show()
```

`Place.csv` file has following data:

```
Name    Place   Capital
A   India   Delhi
B   USA Wash
C   India   Delhi
D   USA Wash
E   China   Bej
F   UK  Lon
G   Canada  un
H   China   Bej
I   UK  Lon
J   UK  Lon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subplot will show two plots side by side:

```
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
place_plot =output2.Place.value_counts().plot(kind="bar",x=output2["Place"],title="Count",legend=False)
 plt.subplot(1,2,2)
capital_plot= output2.Capital.value_counts().plot(kind="bar",x=output2["Capital"],title="Count",legend=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`plt.show()` will produce the figure  window(s). If you call it inthe middle of the script, the script will stop until the window is closed.

If you only call `plt.show()` once at the end, all figures which are produced by the script will be shown at once.